# java compile dependency - will this file be recompiled?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, linker

```
---People (folder) 
------people.java (file) 
------Student (folder)
---------student.java (file)
```

student.java

```
import people.*;
public class student {
   people p
   public student (people p) {
       this.p = p; // dependency injection.
   }
}
```

people.java

```
public class people {
   public people (people p) {
      people p = new student(p);
   }
}
```

The above code people.java depends on student.java, so changes in student.java cause auto-compile of people.java.

But now does student depend on people?
Will change in people.java cause auto-compile in student.java?

Comment: This completely depends on the build tool you're using. Some support incremental builds, so the answer would be "no", some rebuild all the code in the project every time, so the answer would be "yes" but that wouldn't imply any dependency from `People` to `Student`

Comment: Then from perspective of UML, does students depend on people? Does ```extends``` count as dependency.

Comment: Yeah it sure does, but it's unidirectional

Comment: I see. thanks. I modify the code above using dependency injection principle. Does student.java still depend on people.java?  I think it surely does by the name dependency injection (just realized now)..... I asked a dumb question...